# Cycle of a dominant morphism $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb P^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I am referring too Example 1.5.1. In "intersection theory" by Fulton. I am given a dominant morphism $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb P^1$ and we define for a rational function $r$ $[\mathrm{div} (r)] =\sum \mathrm{ord} _W(r) [W] $, where we sum over all codimension 1 varieties. Now if we denote the rational function given by $f$ also by $f$. Why is it that we have $[\mathrm{div} (f)] =[f^{-1}(0)]-[f^{-1}(\infty)]$?

Comment: Can you see that for a $W$, $\mathrm{ord}_W(f)\neq 0$ if and only if $f(W)=0,\infty$?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I do see that the order at the two subvarieties above should have inverse order. I also do not see why the orders are equal to 1 (resp. - 1)

Comment: If you can't see why, I am not sure what your definition of $\mathrm{ord}_W$ is.

Comment: $\mathrm{ord} _V(r) $ is defined to be the length of the $A$-module $A/(r) $ where $A$ denotes the local ring of $V$, i.e. $\mathcal O_{V, W} $. As I only know a definition of this ring over equivalence classes, I don't know how to do explicit calculations with it.

Comment: For what I said, you do not yet need any explicit calculations, just interpret what it means. For example, if $f(W)$ is not zero or infinity, show that $f$ is a unit in $\mathcal{O}_{V,W}$ and thus you get zero.